# Inno Setup uninstaller doesn't remove assembly from GAC

Tags: .net, installation, inno-setup, gac

Installer successfully installs assembly into GAC. However, uninstaller keeps the assembly in GAC.

Am I missing something? I really don't want to use **gacutil.exe** to remove assembly on uninstall.

```
Source: "..\TestHelperInject\bin\x86\Release\TestHelperInject.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: gacinstall sharedfile uninsnosharedfileprompt; StrongAssemblyName: "TestHelperInject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ccbe9854a3cee58d, processorArchitecture=x86"
```

Update: OK, so removing assembly from GAC during uninstall works on WinXP, but not on Win7.

Comment: Can you show us the Inno script section that installs the file?

Comment: Added line which installs the assembly.

Comment: And you're 100% sure that that strong name is 100% correct? If it's not, it won't uninstall it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. But if it wasn't, Inno Setup would refuse to install it in the first place.

Comment: No it wouldn't, the strong name is only used at uninstall. gacinstall uses the file itself to get the information it needs to install it.

Comment: However, if I didn't provide strong assembly name, assembly wouldn't get installed, thus I was forced to provide correct one.

Comment: No, it requires you to specify one, it doesn't have to be "correct" for Inno to compile. From the [help file](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm#StrongAssemblyName): "Specifies the strong assembly name of the file. Used by Uninstall only."

Comment: Deanna: No, none of the answers helped me. Current solution works only on WinXP, not on Win7. My users are using mostly Win7, so I'm still stuck with this.

Comment: So /log didn't show anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From the Inno Setup [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm):

> **gacinstall**
>
> Install the file into the .NET Global Assembly Cache. When
>   used in combination with `sharedfile`, the file will only be uninstalled
>   when the reference count reaches zero.
>
> To uninstall the file Uninstaller uses the strong assembly name
>   specified by parameter `StrongAssemblyName`.
>
> An exception will be raised if an attempt is made to use this flag on
>   a system with no .NET Framework present.

Thus it seems that Inno Setup handles the uninstall for you.

Comment: I've read that documentation. However, assembly is still in GAC after uninstalling application.

Comment: Have you tried using `gacutil` from within your Inno Setup script to uninstall it?

Comment: I could, but I would like to avoid that as I stated in question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not uninstalling it, then it's either marked as in use/shared (see the [`sharedfile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm#sharedfile) flag) or the [`StrongAssemblyName`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_filessection.htm#StrongAssemblyName) is not correct.
Note that Inno only requires that the `StrongAssemblyName` is specified, not that is correct or valid.

Try running the uninstall with the `/log` parameter to see what it reports at uninstall time.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the "processorArchitecture=x86" in the Strong name is a problem. Does this work if you change it to "ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL"?

(This was a hint I picked up from http://odd-staff.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/well.html)